# Select Case wrong output & Mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to VBA Excel although I have coded a few other things. 
I am trying to cross compare a column of numbers between 1 and 0 called the score and the result can be one of 4 depending on the values. However I only ever get the same result (1) regardless of how I code it (I've tried using only "To" or only "<>=") but nothing works. I also can't seem to get it to work through my column, only in one cell at a time (whenever I expand the range to "B2:B7" it gives me a mismatch error.

What I want is for it to actually give me the result I am looking for and working through a column or cells.

Thank you for your time

Here is the code :

```
Sub Vertical_Analysis()

    Sheets("Vertical").Select

    Dim score As Integer
    score = Range("B2").Value

    Dim result As String
    Select Case score
        Case Is >= 0.15
            result = "1"
        Case 0.11 To 0.14
            result = "0.6"
        Case 0.08 To 0.1
            result = "0.3"
        Case Is <= 0.07
            result = "0"
    End Select

    Range("B21").Value = result

End Sub
```

Comment: The reason you are getting only the first is you declared score as an integer.  It needs to be declared as a double `Dim score as Double`

Comment: Thank you so much, I was pretty sure it was an easy fix.

Comment: The first, it fixes the column problem.  My comment fixes your wrong output problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott, works now! I need to figure out the loop bit but thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `score` needs to be a double not an Integer.

Then to loop use a For Each.

The last part `.Range("B21").Offset(i).Value = result` moves each result down one row so that they do not replace each other.

Try this:

```
Sub Vertical_Analysis()

    Dim score As Double, result As String
    Dim Rng As Range, i As Long

    i = 0

    With Sheets("Vertical")
        For Each Rng In .Range("B2:B7")
            score = Rng.Value
            Select Case score
                Case Is >= 0.15
                    result = "1"
                Case 0.11 To 0.14
                    result = "0.6"
                Case 0.08 To 0.1
                    result = "0.3"
                Case Is <= 0.07
                    result = "0"
            End Select
            .Range("B21").Offset(i).Value = result
            i = i + 1
        Next Rng
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome thank you that works.What would I change to that to apply it to the three columns B2:B7 C2:C7 and D2:D7 ? I tried to copy paste and replace Range("B2:B7") with Range("C2:C7") and .Range("C21").Offset(i).Value = result but I ended up with the result input in C26 downwards

Comment: @Lilou please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do and will mark this question as being answered.

Comment: Actually I just created a new macro and works like a dream thank you.